# MYSQL Using CASE Function between Dates

Tags: mysql, case

**SQL Version: MySQL 5.6.32-78.1**

I have this table below:

```
+-----+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| id  | amount   | currency     | date_created | from_date    | thru_date  | product_code |
+-----+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| 101 | 21       |  DUSD        | 2018-01-01   | 2018-01-01   | 2018-01-20 | 01           |
| 101 | 22       |  USD         | 2018-01-02   | 2018-01-21   | NULL       | 01           |
+-----+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
```

I have a date when a sale was made on **2018-01-25** and I try using a query with this line

```
CASE WHEN so.date_created >= pp.date_created 
      AND so.date_created BETWEEN pp.from_date AND pp.thru_date 
         THEN pp.amount 
         ELSE pp.amount 
END
```

Somehow it does not want to work.
It should display 22 but it still displays 21

Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: `THEN pp.amount ELSE pp.amount` means '`pp.amount` in any case'... :)

Comment: *It should display 22 but it still displays 21* Something is wrong. The output must be empty because none of records you show match both conditions. First record do not match `'2018-01-25' BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-20'`, second do not match because of NULL value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look on [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad8836ef831d60371b1ac60c0e02c0df)

```
SELECT pp.*, so.date_created sale_date_created
FROM pp
JOIN so  ON so.date_created >= pp.date_created
        AND so.date_created BETWEEN COALESCE(pp.from_date, so.date_created) AND COALESCE(pp.thru_date, so.date_created);
```

COALESCE() is used to prevent discarding records containing NULL(s).